# in angularJS how change url param without call $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i use angularJS and $routeProvider for route pages ,
how i can change the url params without call routeProvider  and refresh page.
i want change querystring (url param) without check again $routeProvider and recall & refresh .

Comment: i want, disable  $route on a page .  
Because changing the params will refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You could skip angular and use the history api.

```
if (history.pushState) {
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?changedValue=2';
window.history.pushState({path:url},'',url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
 this code also refreshes the page , because ngRoute ($routeProvider) is active